# Jquery UI Mobile returning empty value for form

Tags: jquery, forms, search, mobile

I cannot seem to figure this out. You can view an example of what I've done so far here: http://jsfiddle.net/aCUQC/1/

When a user does a search, an 'x' will appear. Click the 'x' to submit the form.

I am able to 'submit' the form; however, I cannot get it to read the input text value!

**The HTML is as followed:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<br />
<br />
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-mini="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-theme="x">
    <form method="GET" action="search.do" data-ajax="false" style="height: 40px;" id="smartSearch">
        <input data-inline="true" type="text" data-type="search" data-corners="false" name="q" placeholder="Type Name Here (e.g. John Smith)" data-mini="true" autocomplete="off" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**The JS:**

```
$('#smartSearch').on('click', '.ui-input-clear', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the link's default behaviour
    $('form#smartSearch').submit(); 
});
```

Your help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You are targeting the wrong icon - the correct icon to target is `.ui-icon-delete` - You were preventing behavior of the incorrect element.

2) You need to actually do something to get the value. This is where jQuery's [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) comes in handy.

Here is some updated code targeting the correct icon. I used return false instead of prevent default.

```
$("#smartSearch .ui-icon-delete").click(function() {
    var text = $("input").val();
    alert(text);
    $('form#smartSearch').submit(); 
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aCUQC/3/

If you are interested in the difference between return false and prevent default you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have tried using the code above and it just returns an empty string. Any idea why?

Comment: Try giving the input an id in your HTML and instead of var text = $("input").val(); do var text = $("#yourID").val();

Comment: Did you acutally assign the id as "q"? In your code you just have name="q".

Comment: Yes, I have included id="q" in my HTML. Still no luck

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with the code you are using? This is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/aCUQC/4/

Comment: It works after I added $(window).load(function(){ }

Thanks so much!